# Get current line & line index in this contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element like this:

```
<span contenteditable="">line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
</span>
```

Let's say user's editing "line 4". How to get current line & line index (at the caret position) in that contenteditable element ?

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific on your environment? If javascript, do you use a toolkit? What have you tried (with examples)?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've tried to use JS getRange but it's complicated & not always working. If you know a simpler, pure JS solution, it'd be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a simple way to use selection properties and string splitting to count offsets:

```
<pre contenteditable="">line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
</pre>

<button onclick=getPos()>show pos</button>

<script>
function getPos() {
    var sel = document.getSelection(),
        nd = sel.anchorNode,
        text = nd.textContent.slice(0, sel.focusOffset);

    var line=text.split("\n").length;
    var col=text.split("\n").pop().length;
    alert("row:"+line+", col:"+col )
}
</script>
```

obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rvg81kw/

if you have many elements in your editable, you might need to replace `nd.textContent` with `elmWysiwygContainer.textContent` to get the lines of all the text instead of just the "current" node.

Comment: That works! Thanks dandavis! You saved me some hairs :) - cleaned up your example - http://jsfiddle.net/9rvg81kw/1/

Comment: I've tested with the long line and it didn't work. I don't known why?