# Get the current line / line number of the carot in an contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, text, contenteditable, caret

Is there a way to get the current line (i.e. child `div`), or current line number that the caret is on in a `contenteditable` `div`?

I've seen many solutions that can produce the index of the caret, or the total number of lines, but none that can get the specific line that is selected. The closest I've seen is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067475/get-current-line-line-index-in-this-contenteditable-element) which works until the user updates the text.

One hurdle I see is that each new line creates a child `div` element, except the first one. The initial text is part of the `contenteditable`'s direct `innerHTML`. That is unless you delete the first line after creating a new one. In that case every line will have its own `div`.